# How to access enum from QML?

Tags: c++, qt, enums

I have a class which have an enum

Q_PROPERTY(Heatercooler *heatercooler READ heatercooler CONSTANT USER true)

```
 class Heatercooler :  public HardwareComponent
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_ENUMS(HeatTestState)

    public:
        Heatercooler(QObject *parent = 0);
         ~Heatercooler();

        void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *);

        enum HeatTestState
        {
            HEAT_IDLE = 0,
            HEAT_GO_AMBIENT_FOR_HOT,
            HEAT_GO_AMBIENT_FOR_COLD,
            HEAT_GO_AMBIENT_FOR_FINISH,
            HEAT_GO_HOT,
            HEAT_GO_COLD,
            HEAT_FINISH_SUCCESS,
            HEAT_FINISH_ERROR,

            HEAT_LT_COLD,
            HEAT_LT_COLD_Finished,   // lt cold is fifferent from normal cold -> #431
        };

public slots:
      void setState( HeatTestState newstate);

    }
```

I try to access it from a button, but it says that the enum is undefined

```
   Button {
                    text: qsTr("Heater")
                    priority: 1
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    onSecureClicked:  hardware.heatercooler.setState(HEAT_GO_AMBIENT_FOR_HOT)
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're enum is inside the class Heatercooler so you should write `Heatercooler::HEAT_GO_AMBIENT_FOR_HOT`